# Sneak attacks per round

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

I attacked someone that is prone. So I attack with advantage plus sneak attack. Then in his turn he leaves my space which grants me an opportunity attack.

Here's my question: does that opportunity attack grant me another sneak attack? Assuming he is in front of my ally too so he is distracted and he did not disengage.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's break it down:

A **sneak attack** is not any sort of action. It doesn't use your action, bonus action, or reaction. It is simply extra damage added onto *an attack* that meets the requisite conditions. Those are:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{you have advantage}^1 & & \text{finesse weapon} \\ \\
\text{OR} & \text{AND} & \text{OR} \\ \\
\text{you don't have disadvantage and} \\ 
\text{you've an ally who isn't incapacitated} && \text{ranged weapon}\\ \text{within 5' of your target}\\
\end{array}

(Basically, you need one from the first column, one from the second.)

Now, to your attacks:

1. The attack on your turn was made with advantage; as long as you used a ranged or finesse weapon, you got **sneak attack**.
2. The opportunity attack presumably wasn't advantaged,<sup>2</sup> but you had a (presumably non-incapacitated) ally within 5' of the target; as long as you used a ranged or finesse weapon and didn't have *dis*advantage for some reason, you got **sneak attack**.

---

<sup>1 - remember, to say you "have advantage" is to say you've got one or more conditions that would cause advantage and *none* that cause disadvantage. In other words, any source of disadvantage means you don't meet any conditions from column 1. (PHB p.173, "Advantage and Disadvantage")</sup>

<sup>2 - You no longer had the advantage from the opponent being prone, and I'm assuming there was no other source of advantage you didn't mention.</sup>

Comment: The OP is asking if he can even use the ability. Once per turn, but multiple possible times per round is the answer, given in the question to which this is a duplicate.